# TFS 2015 Excel Pivot Table Reporting For Test Plan/Execution

Tags: tfs-2015, mtm

In the past, using TFS 2010/2012 I have been able to create extensive Excel Pivot Table reports for all things QA including Test Plan execution by Executed By, Test Case Priority, Execution trends, etc.

Now at a different place we recently implemented TFS2015 using the Scrum template.  With this TFS instance using the Excel reports there are no possible report fields related to test case execution or test runs.  I can use the web based charts within TFS-TEST but they are extremely limited, partially broken and the only trend report possible is from SSRS.  The SSRS Test Plan Progress report is a pretty graph but it provides limited data points.

Has anyone figured out how to pull advanced data reports on test plans within TFS2015 or is this related to how our instance was implemented?  I'm usually an advanced google-er and have had zero luck.

Answer (score 0):

The [Excel Reports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997876.aspx) can archive the feature you want. Reports you may need:

- [Test Team Productivity Excel Report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee730422.aspx)
- [Test Team Progress Excel
  Report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee730420.aspx)
- [Test Plan Progress Excel Report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd695780.aspx)